# Lodash isEqual returns false for identical objects

Tags: javascript, react-native, lodash

I'm using React Native `memo` to decide whether my component should re-render or not. My props need more than a shallow compare so I figured I can use `Lodash` `isEqual`. However, for some reason it returns false for identical objects. The issue is a prop `userChildren` which is an array of objects. To get it to work I need to remap the whole array which I don't understand why that would be needed.

```
const areEqual = (
  { userChildren: prevChildren, ...prevProps },
  { userChildren: nextChildren, ...nextProps }
) => {
  console.log(
    _.isEqual(
      prevChildren.map((p) => ({ ...p })),
      nextChildren.map((p) => ({ ...p }))
    )
  ); // Returns true
  console.log(_.isEqual(prevChildren, nextChildren)); // Returns false
  console.log(prevChildren);
  console.log(nextChildren);
  return (
    _.isEqual(prevProps, nextProps) &&
    _.isEqual(
      prevChildren.map((p) => ({ ...p })),
      nextChildren.map((p) => ({ ...p }))
    )
  );
};

export default memo(RootNavigator, areEqual);
```

The log output can be seen below:

```
 LOG  true
 LOG  false
 LOG  [{"birthDate": "2022-09-14", "firstName": null, "gender": null, "id": "189", "showGender": null, "userId": "XXX"}]
 LOG  [{"birthDate": "2022-09-14", "firstName": null, "gender": null, "id": "189", "showGender": null, "userId": "XXX"}]
```

**EDIT**

There seems to be something with `nextProps` that breaks the isEqual:

```
console.log(
  'nextChildren',
  _.isEqual(
    [
      {
        birthDate: '2022-09-14',
        firstName: null,
        gender: null,
        id: '189',
        showGender: null,
        userId: 'XXX',
      },
    ],
    nextChildren
  )
);
console.log(
  'prevChildren',
  _.isEqual(prevChildren, [
    {
      birthDate: '2022-09-14',
      firstName: null,
      gender: null,
      id: '189',
      showGender: null,
      userId: 'XXX',
    },
  ])
);
```

Gives the log output:

```
LOG  nextChildren false
LOG  prevChildren true
```

Comment: AFAIK lodash's `.isEqual()` compares objects by reference.

Comment: Does it? I thought the whole point was that it does not: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lodash-_-isequal-method/

Comment: @KarelG you are mistaken.  `_.isEqual({"foo":"bar"}, {"foo":"bar"})` is `true`

Comment: @DanielTovesson Perhaps you could make this into a runnable snippet that fully demonstrates the problem?  See [How do I create a React Stack Snippet with JSX support?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support)

Comment: I tested isEqual with your log output and it is returning true. So the issues is in your props object. Since it is react, the library might include its own properties, which is not openly  available for processing. I am not sure on the exact term on that. I would recommend to convert to string and base64 and compare which would provide proper comparison

Comment: Yeah, you might be correct, I think it's something in nextProps that does not work with `isEqual`, see my edit

Comment: I just wanna get to the bottom of this to avoid any other side effects in the app

Comment: I ended up using the `deep-equal` library instead, that works flawlessly. Keeping this open to see if anyone can figure out the origin of the issue

Comment: In my case, I used `JSON.stringify` and was actually able to see that my objects were different. An `index` key had been added to one of them by some code in a totally different location.